# Memory leak and crash when generating an ANTLR grammar file

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to compile down [this grammar file](http://dirkriehle.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/creole10_wout_extension.g) (for Creole wiki markup) with Antlr 3, but just get a memory leak with the Antlr tool (C# version) and the Java version runs out of heap space:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
        at org.antlr.misc.OrderedHashSet.add(OrderedHashSet.java:67)
        at org.antlr.analysis.DFAState.addNFAConfiguration(DFAState.java:229)
        at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:632)
        at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:708)
        at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:477)
        at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.findNewDFAStatesAndAddDFATransitions(NFAToDFAConverter.java:296)
        at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.convert(NFAToDFAConverter.java:110)
        at org.antlr.analysis.DFA.<init>(DFA.java:237)
        at org.antlr.tool.Grammar.createLookaheadDFA(Grammar.java:1355)
        at org.antlr.tool.Grammar.createLookaheadDFAs(Grammar.java:1119)
        at org.antlr.tool.Grammar.createLookaheadDFAs(Grammar.java:1069)
        at org.antlr.codegen.Target.performGrammarAnalysis(Target.java:118)
        at org.antlr.codegen.JavaTarget.performGrammarAnalysis(JavaTarget.java:54)
        at org.antlr.codegen.CodeGenerator.genRecognizer(CodeGenerator.java:286)
        at org.antlr.Tool.generateRecognizer(Tool.java:696)
        at org.antlr.Tool.process(Tool.java:509)
        at org.antlr.Tool.main(Tool.java:98)
```

Is there some way to get the grammar to compile?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the Java heap and stack space already?

Comment: @apalala it does the same with the. Nett tool but eats 5gb of ram

Comment: @ChrisS. I have faced with same problem in my practice. It could be solved by a simplification of your grammar without reduction of its functionality. (As for me, I could try to refactor it only for some bounty. Sorry :))

Comment: @Andremoniy sure, if you have the time. It's 22 hours until it can have a bounty

Comment: @Andremoniy, you're going to answer for a *bounty*?! Are you serious?!

Comment: @BartKiers You have put me in shame :)

Comment: @Andremoniy, no, you did that yourself by begging for a bounty. :)

Comment: @BartKiers ok, for bounty I could spend some considerable time and try to force this grammar be compiled under Antlr 3.5. Ok?

Comment: @Andremoniy feel free to do so. I just don't understand you need a bounty for it. I understand you might like helping people, or you might like the challenge in solving a particular (ANTLR) problem, but doing something you wouldn't do if you don't get reputation-points for it is just silly (all IMHO, of course!). Or are SO reputation points hard currency in your country? I might move in that case... :)

Answer (score 1):

[ANTLR v3.2](http://antlr.org/download/antlr-3.2.jar) is able to generate a lexer and parser from this grammar. Albeit with a lot of warnings, but it does generate the files.

Comment: Ok, why not 3.5? What's the difference?

Comment: All versions are open source: you do the *diff* :)

Comment: The authors of the grammar have said they're not supporting ANTLR anymore, so I may have to just start from scratch with Antlr 4

Comment: @ChrisS., yeah, ANTLR 4 is a much better options w.r.t. parsing ambiguous grammars like this Wiki-style Creole.